# The size of the button has risen on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMI0O.png)

I tried all the button types of flutter, but the horizontal size does not change in all of them.

Comment: Please make sure to follow the code of conduct and paste your code into your question. Buttons usually take the width of their parent. So if you use a SizedBox as parent you can limit the size. You can also set padding or margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
 `style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size([width], [height])),`
Example:

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('240 x 80'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              fixedSize: const Size(240, 80), primary: Colors.deepOrange),
        ),
```